# jQuery focus after blur() last form field

Tags: jquery, blur

Following code should focus the first form element after blurring the last one ,but this is not  happening:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#last").blur(function(){
     $("#first").focus();
  });
});
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" name="first" id="first"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="last" id="last">
</form>
```

If I add another form element after #last, it's working correctly, see below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#last").blur(function(){
     $("#first").focus();
  });
});
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" name="first" id="first"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="last" id="last">
<input type="text" name="dummy">
</form>
```

Comment: It works for me if I click out of the second field, not if I tab out, but I think that's because with tab, it ends up jumping into another frame...http://jsfiddle.net/bUt9M/

Comment: You are correct, I'm using tab out, but this blurs the input field so it's supposed to work ?

Comment: I added an answer with a fix for your tab issues, let me know if that works for ya ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix for you, it's working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bUt9M/2/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#last").blur(function(){
     $("#first").focus();
  });
    $("#last").keydown(function(e) {
         if(e.keyCode == 9) {
            $("#first").focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ` e.preventDefault();` for all keys ??

Comment: Fixed it, thanks again.. works on FF and Chrome (can't test IE right now)

Comment: Thanks, should this be reported to jQuery ? Or is this a normal behaviour ?

Comment: It's not a jQuery issue, I think Chrome doesn't really like preventDefault (and I think IE has issues with it as well).

Answer (score 1):

As @Deleteman said in the comment:

> It works for me if I click out of the second field, not if I tab out,
>   but I think that's because with tab, it ends up jumping into another
>   frame.

He is right, and I have a solution for you.

Here is the safe solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#last").keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==9)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#first").focus();
        }
    });
  $("#last").blur(function(e){
     $("#first").focus();
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uGudk/

Answer (score -1):

thow [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Bmdwn/2/) it is working fine maybe you are not including jquery in your code

Comment: ya, but the problem to him only with two elements, but it is working fine

Comment: could you tell me, what's the wrong in the code and answer, and why you think it like a down vote